# wpf c#: label with superscript and subscript

Tags: c#, wpf, label, subscript, superscript

In my WPF application, C# based, I need to have some labels with superscript and subscript, as usually in various maths operations. For example:

E<sub>s</sub>/E<sub>m</sub>

or

4<sup>x</sup>

I need to understand how to create labels int this way both in XAML and via code.
Anyone can help me? I only found something about Windows Forms, but nothing about WPF.
Thanks for your help

EDIT:
The other post describes only XAML solution, that does not work for me. Do I need to change size of characters to have subscript / superscript??Plus, I need to have a solution to create label with superscript / subscript via code and not only via XAML.

Comment: I've tried that code for XAML and it does not work.

Answer (score 3):

Use Typography.Variants, which meant to have subscript/ superscript style rendering. [Ref](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.typography.variants.aspx).

MDSN example

[image]

```
<Paragraph FontFamily="Palatino Linotype">
  2<Run Typography.Variants="Superscript">3</Run>
  14<Run Typography.Variants="Superscript">th</Run>
</Paragraph>
```

[image]

```
<Paragraph FontFamily="Palatino Linotype">
  H<Run Typography.Variants="Subscript">2</Run>O
  Footnote<Run Typography.Variants="Subscript">4</Run>
</Paragraph>
```

Comment: I've tried this `<TextBlock><Run>Normal Text</Run>2<Run Typography.Variants="Superscript">3</Run>3<Run Typography.Variants="Subscript">4</Run></TextBlock>` but it does not work for me. Paragraph is not present in Visual Studio and I cannot add it via code in XAML.

Comment: Refer relevant namespace and in this case it is System.Windows.Documents (in PresentationFramework.dll). ref : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.documents.paragraph.aspx

Comment: Done, but IDE tells me that it is impossible to assing the specified value.

Comment: In the link of your last comment, there is no refer to namespace System.Windows.Documents in the example at bottom of page.

Comment: To resolve issue, I've used the BaselineAlignment directive in the XAML. Now I need to know how to use it in C#, because I need to write textblock with the following text: ag (g) with first 'g' as subscript...please help